# grsync crashes on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, grsync

Grsync installed on ubuntu 19.04 without problems, and grsync will start. However, when the "go" icon is clicked, grsync crashes.  Anybody have any ideas why?  Thanks.

Comment: it would be helpful if you paste any logs with crash info, screenshot, whatsoever

Comment: Well, the crash log file has over 19500 entries! Rather large to paste here.

Answer (score 0):

Upon research and advice from kind people, I have learned grsync must be invoked by the terminal command "sudo grsync". In my case, grsync loaded and ran, but displayed many unusual errors, which I hope to resolve ere long. Thank you.